# how to use is.na() with dplyr, when column name is stored as string?

Tags: r, dplyr, na, tidyeval

I'm new to tidy evaluation- although some things make sense, I usually just try different combinations of {{}}, !! + quo, sym() etc.

But I can't get is.na() to work? here's an example:

```
column <- "Sepal.Length"
iris_na <- rbind(iris, rep(NA,5))
iris_na %>%
  subset(is.na(column))
```

Comment: The reason your attempts didn't work is that `subset` isn't a ‘dplyr’ function and performs no tidy evaluation.

Comment: With `dplyr`, use `iris_na %>% filter(is.na(.data[[column]]))`. `filter` is the dplyr version of the base R function `subset`

Comment: you can try with this syntax `iris_na[column] %>% subset(is.na(.))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple use `get`

```
 iris_na %>%
    subset(is.na(get(column)))
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
151           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
```

Also you can use `filter` instead of `subset` and get the same result